# How to prevent blank posting when page is refreshed

Tags: php, forms, email

Please I will need your help.

I have an online form (http://mmg2015.org/participationform.php) that post data to the back end database. Its works very well. But I decided to add an email code, as seen below, such that when the form is submitted, a copy of the form contents will be sent to the email box so the admin will be able to acknowledge and respond.

Now since I added the email code, the form keep posing blank fields to my email box when ever the page/form is refreshed. Nothing is posted to the database since there are no contents but my email keep receiving empty emails from the form.

Can any one please help me determine why it is posting blank.

```
<?php
$emailSubject = 'A new application for participation!';
$webMaster = 'info@mmg2015.org';

// $email and $message are the data that is being
// posted to this page from our html contact form
$nameoforganisation = $_POST['nameoforganisation'] ;
$sector = $_POST['sector'] ;
$address = $_POST['address'] ;
$email = $_POST['p1email'] ;
$p1name = $_POST['p1name'] ;
$p1phone = $_POST['p1phone'] ;
$p1designation = $_POST['p1designation'] ;
$p1email = $_POST['p1email'] ;
$p2name = $_POST['p2name'] ;
$p2phone = $_POST['p2phone'] ;
$p2designation = $_POST['p2designation'] ;
$p2email = $_POST['p2email'] ;
$signature = $_POST['signature'] ;

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name of Organisation: $nameoforganisation <br>
Sector: $sector <br>
Address: $address <br>

First Participants Details:<br>

Name: $p1name <br>
Phone: $p1phone <br>
Designation: $p1designation <br>
Email: $p1email <br>

Second Participants Details:<br>

Name: $p2name <br>
Phone: $p2phone <br>
Designation: $p2designation <br>
Email: $p2email <br>

Signature: $signature <br>
EOD;
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
?>
```

I appreciate with plenty of thanks

Mike

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to header injection.

Comment: What about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get ?

Comment: @PeeHaa: Please how can I handle that? Could you send me a hint on how to handle header injection

Comment: The link @JohnConde provided should be able to tell you that

Comment: @PeeHaa: Ok! I will work on the header issue but the important issue now is to resolve the form post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following to different conditions:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_form_submit_button_name']))
{
//put your insert code and send mail from here
}
```

Another is :
After database insert you will get last insert id. Put a condition id the code get last insert id then send mail.

Comment: I believe you mean the Submit button right?? Meanwhile thank you for your comment.

Comment: I simply added the code you sent and replaced the 'user_form_submit_button_name' with 'Submit', uploaded the page, refreshed it 3 times and check my email box, there were no empty mails sent as usual. Thank you all. Next now is to work on the header injection

Answer (score 0):

You don't check to see if a form submission occurred or even if you have valid data before you send your email. So every page load results in an email being sent.

Wrap this code in an if statement that at least checks for a form submission (although validating the data you receive should occur as well):

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $emailSubject = 'A new application for participation!';
    $webMaster = 'info@mmg2015.org';

    // $email and $message are the data that is being
    // posted to this page from our html contact form
    $nameoforganisation = $_POST['nameoforganisation'] ;
    $sector = $_POST['sector'] ;
    $address = $_POST['address'] ;
    $email = $_POST['p1email'] ;
    $p1name = $_POST['p1name'] ;
    $p1phone = $_POST['p1phone'] ;
    $p1designation = $_POST['p1designation'] ;
    $p1email = $_POST['p1email'] ;
    $p2name = $_POST['p2name'] ;
    $p2phone = $_POST['p2phone'] ;
    $p2designation = $_POST['p2designation'] ;
    $p2email = $_POST['p2email'] ;
    $signature = $_POST['signature'] ;

    $body = <<<EOD
    <br><hr><br>
    Name of Organisation: $nameoforganisation <br>
    Sector: $sector <br>
    Address: $address <br>

    First Participants Details:<br>

    Name: $p1name <br>
    Phone: $p1phone <br>
    Designation: $p1designation <br>
    Email: $p1email <br>

    Second Participants Details:<br>

    Name: $p2name <br>
    Phone: $p2phone <br>
    Designation: $p2designation <br>
    Email: $p2email <br>

    Signature: $signature <br>
    EOD;
    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
}
?>
```

You also don't [sanitize the submitted data](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/228389-preventing-php-mail-header-injections/) which leaves your script vulnerable to sending spam.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Is it OK to use this $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {........ since its what I already have in my code system generated byDreamweaver. If not, what can I use there pls???

Comment: I really dont understand what you mean by "REQUEST_METHOD" or should I use the code the way you wrote it???